Is there any way to control the Media like chrome does from the console/javascript?
The implementation is not important, but I would like to have functions or calls I can make to skip forward/backward, play/pause and a track i can move / function to call to change the song position as chrome does. This pretty much needs to only work on spotify / as a console or js insert.
This is what I am talking about:

I know that I can get metadata from the MediaSession API, but how can I fiddle with the playback? Mainly I care about changing the song position. However a full implementation/what I can call would be nice.
I don't know where to start.

what you seem to be asking is how to use audio in a browser with custom controls?

HTMLMediaElement instance properties should help with the basics, e.g. you can seek within a track by setting the currentTime property, possibly requiring metadata to have been loaded. I'm unaware of inbuilt browser support for playlists to support moving between tracks that are played separately - you may have to find or write your own code.
